# Django Forms With foreign key

Tags: django, forms, django-models

I have 2 models in django, and im also using ModelForm, my question is the second model have a froreignkey of the 1, and i want to have one page when generating the form. It's possible, how to link the two forms in one page.

```
Class Event(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField()

class Date(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   start = models.DateTimeField()
   end = models.DateTimeField()
   event = models.ForeignKey("Event")
```

I also have

```
class EventForm(ModelForm)
Class Date(ModelForm)
```

What i want is to create the event in one page in my templates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have this on the Django Admin, then you need to use [inline models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).
If you plan to create your own form (using ModelForms), then you need to use [inline formets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

Comment: Thank you, i will try, i whant to create my own form without using the django Admin

Comment: i tried but when i want to create an event, i got a form just with the start and end 3 times, the name is not displayed. Thanks.
EventInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Event, Date)
and i create the formset like a form.